# Difference between char pointer and char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

> I have defined 2 variables, one a pointer and one an array

```
char* ptr;
char* array;

ptr = "12345";
array = new int[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    array[i] = i;

while(*ptr != 0)
        cout << *ptr++ << endl;

//Get garbage values
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout << ptr[i];
```

> I was wondering what are the major differences between the variables. 
>   And why I get garbage values when I try to print the values in "ptr[]"
>   the  array way, but it's perfectly fine when iterate through the
>   vales. I can't seem to understand how my variable "ptr" can point to 5
>   characters, since  it should only be able to point to one.

Comment: Hint: `ptr++` changes the value of `ptr`. You never reset it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many differences between pointers and arrays, but the reason you are getting garbage, is that by the time you use `ptr` with an index, it already points to the null terminator of "12345".

Everytime you do this:

```
*ptr++;
```

`ptr` points to the next element it used to point (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ...). When the loop ends, it points to the null terminator `\0` and then when you try to index it with `i`, it points to unknown memory.

I suggest you use a temp pointer to iterate through the elements instead:

```
const char* ptr; // declaring ptr constant in this case is a good idea as well

...

ptr = "12345";
char *tmp = ptr;

...

while(*tmp != 0)
    cout << *tmp++ << endl;
```

Comment: Is there a way to reset the variable rather than going into a loop and decrementing it?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal: Huh? This code is well-defined: `int main() { const char* ptr = "12345"; }`.

Comment: @SidharthMudgal How can it cause a buffer overflow? Granted it should not be modified which is why I suggested using a constant pointer.

Comment: Assigning a string pointer is not like doing a strcpy(), it's only setting the pointer to point to a different location (in this case, to a location in the executable where the string "12345" has been stored statically by the compiler).

Comment: @SidharthMudgal: That's fine too (though that needs to be `const char*` in C++11). Why don't *you* expand on how that causes overflows?

Answer (score 2):

You really have three concepts in play here: pointers to characters, dynamic arrays and string literals:

```
    // Initialise a character pointer to point to a dynamic array of characters
    char* array = new char[5];

    // Assign values pointed to.
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        array[i] = i;
    // Read back the values.
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         std::cout << array[i];

    // Initialise a character pointer to point to a string literal.
    const char* const ptr = "12345";

    const char* charIterator = ptr;
    while(*charIterator != 0)
        std::cout << *charIterator << std::endl;

    //Another way to read values.
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        std::cout << ptr[i];
```

Note the double use of `const` in the expression `const char* const ptr`. The first means that the character values are constant, the second the pointer itself is constant. It is the latter that prevents writing `ptr++`, and losing your only handle to the address of the start of the string literal `"12345"`.

Comment: So const char* ptr = ... causes the "12345" to never change. Why should I add the const after char*? What is the advantage?

Comment: As noted above, it gives an error if you write `ptr++`, which was the reason for you getting the garbage values,

Answer (score 0):

If you use pointer ptr directly,the address which ptr stored that point to the array's value would be change.In this loop:

```
while(*ptr != 0)

   cout << *ptr++ << endl;
```

now, ptr points to the end of the array(\0).

Maybe you should execute the last loop before the loop above.

Usually,do as Nick's way is more appropriate.

Comment: When ptr reaches the end or \0 and I print out that value, will it show an empty space?